# Scala strange implicit boxing conversion error

Tags: scala, boxing, lifting

Can someone tell me why the following does not work?

```
object TestObject {
    def map(f: (Double, Double) => Double, x2: Array[Double]) = {
        val y = x2.zip( x2 )
        val z = y.map(f)
        z
    }
}
```

Produces this error:

```
type mismatch; found : (Double, Double) => Double required: ((Double, Double)) => ?
```

Answer (score 4):

In this snippet, `f` is a function taking two `Double` parameters and returning a `Double`.
You are attempting to call `f` by passing a single argument of type `Tuple2[Double,Double]`.
You can fix this by changing the type of `f` in the first place:

```
object TestObject {
    def map(f: ((Double, Double)) => Double, x2: Array[Double]) = {
        val y = x2.zip( x2 )
        val z = y.map(f)
        z
    }
}
```

You could also declare it as `f: Tuple2[Double, Double] => Double` to be clearer (this is entirely equivalent).

Conversely, you could change your call like this:

```
object TestObject {
    def map(f: (Double, Double) => Double, x2: Array[Double]) = {
        val y = x2.zip( x2 )
        val z = y.map(f.tupled)
        z
    }
}
```

`tupled` automagically transforms your `(Double, Double) => Double` function into a `Tuple2[Double, Double] => Double` function.
Keep in mind however that the conversion will be done on each call to `TestObject.map`

Comment: Or keep the signature and use `val z = y.map(f.tupled)`

Comment: also, rather than `val z = y.map(f.tupled); z;` just use `y.map(f.tupled)`. Looks much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between

```
f: (Double, Double) => Double // two Double arguments -> Double
```

and

```
f: ((Double, Double)) => Double // one Tuple2[Double, Double] argument -> Double
```

`y` is an `Array[(Double, Double)]`, so it expects a method that takes a tuple and returns something, but the first `f` defined above doesn't match that.

You can do `y.map(f.tupled)` to go from the first to the second, or change the signature of `f`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that `f` expects two `Double` arguments but you're attempting to pass it a single tuple: `f((1, 2))` is different from `f(1, 2)`.

Change the type of f to `((Double, Double) => Double)` and it should work.